# Insert Dataframe data to a map using Geopandas

Tags: pandas, plot, geopandas

I need to insert some coordinates from a dataframe to a map. For this task I am using geopandas.

This is my code:

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(DF, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(DF.pickup_longitude, DF.pickup_latitude))
```

I got the following:

```
 Unnamed: 0  DOLocationID  ...  time                    geometry
0           0           NaN  ...     0.380278  POINT (-74.01576 40.71555)
1           1           NaN  ...     0.390833  POINT (-73.98205 40.76276)
2           2           NaN  ...     0.350556  POINT (-73.97941 40.75543)
3           3           NaN  ...     0.503056  POINT (-73.77679 40.64509)
4           4           NaN  ...     0.618333  POINT (-73.78806 40.64167)

[5 rows x 31 columns]
```

Then I create the map using this code:

```
df = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('nybb'))
df = df.to_crs(epsg=3857)
ax = df.plot(figsize=(10, 10), alpha=0.5, edgecolor='k')
ctx.add_basemap(ax)
```

So my question is: how do I plot the geometry column into the map?

PD: I tried `gdf.plot(ax=ax, color='red')` before the last line because I understood geopandas automatically  reference the column `geometry`. However, the map change when I did it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your `gdf` is in different CRS than df once you reproject it. I assume that gdf is in lon/lat coordinates, which is epsg 4326. So you first have to set it to your gdf and then reproject to 3857 as you did with the other one.

```
gdf.crs = 4326
gdf = gdf.to_crs(3857)
```

Then you can plot as you already tried.

```
df = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('nybb'))
df = df.to_crs(epsg=3857)
ax = df.plot(figsize=(10, 10), alpha=0.5, edgecolor='k')
gdf.plot(ax=ax, color='red')
ctx.add_basemap(ax)
```

Comment: unfortunately the issue persists. The map changes (all Noth America instead of New York) and the points from the dataframe are in differents parts. I tried with 4326 in the entire code and I got the same result.

Comment: In that case it seems that `gdf.crs` is different. So you have to assign the actual one instead of 4326.